# Premiere Garbage Mask Not Rendering Correctly

Tags: premiere

I am working on a Premiere project that will be exported for YouTube. At the end, there is a screen with two boxes in which I've placed clips of my previous videos. These will be annotations on YouTube. The background of this end screen is a timelapse video that I took of a white board drawing being created. So, in order to 'cut out' the boxes where the annotation video clips will play, I used garbage masks. Everything looks great in Premiere. But when I render it, the background white board video disappears. It's just the two smaller annotation video clips on a black background. What am I doing wrong?

TLDR: The clip on which I've placed my garbage mask is rendering black when I export it.

Comment: So are you applying the garbage matte to the whiteboard clip or the annotation clips?

Comment: @stib I used the 16-point garbage mask and put it over the square where the annotation clip will play. Then I added the Alpha Adjust effect and selected Invert Alpha. This is my first time using a mask in Premiere, so maybe I'm just doing everything backwards. But it plays the way I want it to look in Premiere. It's just when I export it that it looks weird.

Comment: Try adding the mask to the annotation layers, you shouldn't have to use the invert alpha effect. And you won't need any masks or alpha effects on your background.